# Bayesian statistics and convergence to "the true distribution"

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, bayesian, bayes-theorem

Suppose we have a random variable $\mathbb X : \Omega \to E$ and let's define random variables $\mathbb Y_1, \mathbb Y_2, \mathbb Y_3, \ldots, $ all i.i.d to $\mathbb X$. Now we choose an arbitrary distribution $\mathbb Z_0$ with the same range as $\mathbb X$, called our prior.

Now we define our posterior random variable $\mathbb Z_1$ via Bayesian adjustment according to Bayes' law observing $\mathbb Y_1$. Consider $\mathbb Z_1$ to be our prior. Repeat this and define a sequence $\left\{\mathbb Z_n \right\}_{n=1}^\infty$.

Does it make sense to talk about a limit whereas $\mathbb Z_n \to \mathbb X$ in probability, meaning that for all $\varepsilon >0$ we have $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty} \mathbb P(\mathbb| Z_n - \mathbb X| < \varepsilon) = 1$? Does a stochastic random variable $\mathbb Z_0$ always exist?

Comment: Yes, it makes sense.

Comment: I prefer to call it the "population distribution" rather than the "true distribution". Other probability distributions involved in the problem are not less "true". $\qquad$

Comment: @DavidG.Stork In what way does it make sense? Will a such initial $\mathbb Z_0$ always exist?

Comment: Frankly, my answer was somewhat ironic, because your question was so vague, so unfocused and un-answerable.  You asked "does it make sense...?" to which the answer is "yes."  If you want to ask a better question, you'll more likely get a better answer.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork I think it's quite clear. We want to "find" $\mathbb X$ by defining a sequence of $\mathbb Z_k$s and each iteration is defined by using Bayes' law to update the distribution in the light of a new observation $\mathbb Y_k$. The question is about a limiting process as $k\to\infty.$

Comment: $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty} \mathbb P(| \mathbb Z_n - \mathbb X| < \varepsilon) = 1$ does not make sense as the best you can hope for is $\mathbb Z_n \to \mathbb X$ in distribution rather than in probability.  Even then it does not make much sense unless you are talking about a discrete random variable or you have some other information to use for your *Bayesian adjustment*